# fatal error: mach-o/dyld.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile this src on my Ubuntu 14: https://github.com/Bohdan-Khomtchouk/HeatmapGenerator/blob/master/HeatmapGenerator2_Macintosh_OSX.cxx.

To compile this source code, do: `fltk-config --use-images --use-gl --compile HeatmapGenerator2_Macintosh_OSX.cxx`

However, I retrieve the following error:

```
HeatmapGenerator2_Macintosh_OSX.cxx:52:25: fatal error: mach-o/dyld.h: 
No such file or directory
  #include <mach-o/dyld.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've looked into http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1623945 but it didn't help solve my issue.

Is `#include <mach-o/dyld.h>` not a valid preprocessor directive in Ubuntu?  There seems to be very little written about it on the Internet.  Perhaps it is an Apple specific library that might not be included in Ubuntu?

Any suggestions on how to bypass this error and successfully generate a binary executable file are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

When I comment out the `#include <mach-o/dyld.h>` preprocessor directive, I get the following error:

```
HeatmapGenerator_Macintosh_OSX.cxx:568:13: error: use of undeclared identifier
      '_NSGetExecutablePath'
        if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) == 0)
```

Is there a way to bypass this error without using this preprocessor directive? `_NSGetExecutablePath` is only used once in the src, perhaps there exists an alternative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That source code simply won't compile under Linux as it's designed to use OSX's `dylib` (dynamic loader) rather than Linux's dynamic loader.

Possible solutions:

- "Port" the source code from OSX to Linux.
- Use OSX to compile the file.

Comment: Can you explain the "port" suggestion?

Comment: Well as with any platform-specific functionality, you need to provide the equivalent functionality on the ported platform.  If that is restricted to the dynamic loader then it should be pretty easy, as most platforms, including Windows, provide functions for loading library files and finding symbols within the loaded libraries in order to call those functions.

Comment: So are you saying that I can modify this OS X src to provide a function for loading library and finding symbols within the loaded libraries (since `dylib` looks like the issue involved)?

Comment: Yeah that's right - however it really depends on how much OSX-specific functionality is used in the file.

Comment: How about this: http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/hoanga/2003/08/25/os-xs-version-of-ldd/

Comment: My use of the command `ldd` was misleading.  [This](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) is the equivalent Linux functionality.

Comment: Please see edit made in original question... any thoughts on this?  I'm wondering if there is a way to side-step `_NSGetExecutablePath`, which is used only once in the code.

Comment: @warship That can be obtained from `argv[0]` in `main()` and can get assigned to a global variable.